# Understanding the introductory code snippet for Haskell's popular optparse-applicative library

Tags: haskell, optparse

From an introductory code snippet from the popular [optparse](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) library:

```
data Sample = Sample
  { hello :: String
  , quiet :: Bool }

sample :: Parser Sample
sample = Sample
  <$> strOption -- Q1
      ( long "hello"
     <> metavar "TARGET" -- Q2
     <> help "Target for the greeting" )
  <*> switch
      ( long "quiet"
     <> help "Whether to be quiet" )
```

See the comments in the code snippet for my questions/confusion.

Q1: How is it that `<$>` can be used as the first argument of the type constructor `Sample`? I thought this operation had to be used between a function and a functor.

Q2: What is the operation `<>` used throughout this code snippet?

Comment: A note on terminology: the second argument of `(<$>)` is not "a functor". `Parser` is the functor involved here, as opposed to any particular `Parser`-values you might make use of. I usually call such values "functorial values", even though that is somewhat unwieldy jargon. (Sorry for the rather annoying nitpicking. It is just that it is worth pointing out this particular mix-up because it can lead to further confusion down the road.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Q1: How is it that `<$>` can be used as the first argument of the type constructor Sample? I thought this operation had to be used between a function and a functor.

It is the other way around: `Sample` is the first argument of `(<$>)`, and it is being mapped over the `Parser String` produced by `strOption`.

> Q2: What is the operation `<>` used throughout this code snippet?

`(<>)` is a synonym for `mappend`, from the [`Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) class. In this case, it is being used to combine individual settings into the set of settings to be used for each of the command-line options that you are defining.

Comment: So the data constructor `Sample`, as the first argument of `(<$>)`, is being treated as a normal function?

Comment: @George Yes; you can see with `:t Sample` that it is effectively a function with type `String -> Bool -> Sample`.

Comment: @George Yup, as chepner says a constructor is just a normal function (that it can also be used for pattern matching doesn't affect that).

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ApplicativeDo` and [`NamedFieldPuns`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#record-puns) extensions, one could also write it like this:

```
{-# language ApplicativeDo #-}
{-# language NamedFieldPuns #-}
import Options.Applicative
import Data.Monoid

data Sample = Sample
  { hello :: String
  , quiet :: Bool }

sample :: Parser Sample
sample = do
    hello <- strOption ( long "hello"
                      <> metavar "TARGET"
                      <> help "Target for the greeting" )
    quiet <- switch ( long "quiet"
                   <> help "Whether to be quiet" )
    pure (Sample {hello,quiet})
```